# redis vs memcached vs levelDB use cases

Tags: redis, memcached, leveldb

I read some time ago [this](https://medium.com/@Alibaba_Cloud/redis-vs-memcached-in-memory-data-storage-systems-3395279b0941) this article which explains pretty well, the difference between redis and memcached, and now I wanted to get a similar article about levelDB vs any of those, or both of them, but I can't. I did find a comparison in terms of features, supported languages, etc., but what I would really like to know is when would I choose one over another.

I'd like to understand the use cases; in terms of which one suits best in which type of applications, or which type of data.

Answer (score 0):

Leveldb offers such functionality as read snapshots and atomic writes. With this you could build a relational db on top. Redis offers different data structures for various efficient algorithms (https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/introduction/).

And of course one is on disk, another is in-memory.

Comment: redis' persistence is on disk, but all they are in-memory. So in which case I would go gor levelDB instead of memcached, for example. What kind of application do I have to have?

Comment: @suren the kind where you have a lot more data than RAM